# How can I plot the quantity of a group in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, bar-chart

I am using a Twitter data set (@realDonaldTrump). On this data set I want to do some NLP stuff. 
Right now I would like to plot the quantity of the column "Source".
The data frame looks like that (I cropped it):

```
    User                Tweet_ID            Source      
0   @realDonaldTrump    1138445389709885445 Twitter for iPhone  
1   @realDonaldTrump    1138444530020245505 Twitter for iPhone
```

I already tried to plot all the objects in "Source" using `groupby().count()`:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
df_trump = pd.read_csv('@realDonaldTrump_tweets.csv')
df = df_trump
df
df.groupby([df.Source]).count().plot(kind='bar')
```

I get a nice plot, but I only want one(!) bar for each object. Not all the headers displayed. So in this following picture, the "Twitter for iPhone" bar should be one bar with not the data frame headers displayed.

[Output: Bar Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h81Zb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look at the aggregated dataframe to understand what is happening:

```py
df.groupby([df.Source]).count().head()
```

You will get an output like this:

```
                     User Tweet_id Created_at Retweet_count Favorite_count  Text
source      
Twitter Media Studio 2    2        2          2             2               2
Twitter for iPad     2    2        2          2             2               2
Twitter for iPhone   2    2        2          2             2               2
```

You see that the aggregation (count) was applied to all of the remaining columns which weren't used for the groupby.

As a quick fix you could do something like this to plot only one of the columns:

```py
df.groupby([df.source]).count()['User'].plot(kind='bar')
```